# Twitter API "retweeted_status" field in "home_timeline" request

Tags: iphone, twitter, mgtwitterengine

I'm using MGTwitterEngine + OAuth in my iPhone application. All works fine, but when I'm requesting home_timeline of friends_timeline with include_rt option I'm not getting retweeted_status field.

dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/home_timeline
Responce should contain "retweeted_status" structure for retweets (as you can see in the sample). It describes source tweet that was retweeted.

dev.twitter.com/console
If you will use Twitter Console - you will get this structure successfully.

But my app recieves this structure as empty. Like " < retweeted_status>\n< /retweeted_status>".
All requests are working great except this.

Have anyone seen this? What's the solution?

PS: I've find this
http://www.mail-archive.com/twitter-development-talk@googlegroups.com/msg25383.html
and a few similar discussions, but this is madness if it is true. )

Thanks.

Comment: Even I do have the same issue which is already posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496718/retweet-using-oathmgtwitterengine-not-getting-update-response

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer. It was so simple.
SAOAuthTwitterEngine engine uses MGTwitterEngine but allows it to use OAuth.
But this engine is using MGTwitterEngine created in 2008, when MGTwitterEngine didn't know about "retweeted_status" because this feature appeared later.

Anyway.
All I was need to do - if to add [elementName isEqualToString:@"retweeted_status"] case for

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)theParser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
  attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict

and

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)theParser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName

methods in MGTwitterStatusesParser.m similarly to [elementName isEqualToString:@"status"] case.